# Compute Average Scores from HashMaps

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not sure how to put this into code. I'm building this small code block in which gives the quotient of two numbers from two HashMaps that has the same key by building a new one and put the key and the new number there. e.g. HashMap1 have {a=6} and HashMap2 have {a=3}. Then HashMap3 would put {a=2}.
This is the code I'm working on.

```
    /**
     * Given a list of reviews from the file, this method computes the average score
     * for each word in the reviews and stores that score in the wordValue HashMap,
     * where the key is the word and the value is the average score.
     * 
     * To get the average score, first compute the total score for a word and the
     * number of times it appears.
     * 
     * As a slight improvement, only store the word in wordValue if the score is not
     * an average word - if the score is less than 1.75 or greater than 2.25.
     * 
     * @param reviews An ArrayList of lines representing reviews. The first word in
     *                each line is a score.
     */
    public void computeWordValue(ArrayList<String> reviews) {

        // Initialize any needed HashMaps
        HashMap<String, Integer> totalScores = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<>();
        // Compute the word total scores and counts using the appropriate method.
        computeScoreAndCounts(reviews, totalScores, wordCount);
        // Build a HashMap of average scores
        HashMap<String, Double> avgScoresMap = new HashMap<>();//I'm assuming this is empty

        for (String wordKey : reviews) {
            
            if (avgScoresMap.containsKey(wordKey)) {
                Double avgScore = (double) (totalScores.get(wordKey) / wordCount.get(wordKey)); //I think this is why it doesn't work
                avgScoresMap.put(wordKey, avgScore);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(avgScoresMap);
    }
```

I'm not sure why this does not work, it only prints out nothing or "{}". Don't worry about the first two HashMaps.
In regards, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem.

```
HashMap<String, Double> avgScoresMap = new HashMap<>();//I'm assuming this is empty
for (String wordKey : reviews){
    if (avgScoresMap.containsKey(wordKey)) {
            Double avgScore = (double) (totalScores.get(wordKey)
                    / wordCount.get(wordKey)); // I think this is why it doesn't work
            avgScoresMap.put(wordKey, avgScore);
    }
}
```

As you said, the hashmap is empty. So it can't contain anything so your `containsKey` fails.  Thus you never put anything in the map.  Change it so that it checks if it isn't in the map.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
 for (String wordKey : reviews) {
            
            if (avgScoresMap.containsKey(wordKey)) {
                Double avgScore = (double) (totalScores.get(wordKey) / wordCount.get(wordKey)); //I think this is why it doesn't work
                avgScoresMap.put(wordKey, avgScore);
            }

        }
```

However, it's not `if (avgScoresMap.containsKey(wordKey))`, it should be `if (!avgScoresMap.containsKey(wordKey))` since you're checking if the map don't contain the key. If you don't do that, it's never going to put the data into the `HashMap`. Or in other words, this should be your method:

```
public void computeWordValue(ArrayList<String> reviews) {

        // Initialize any needed HashMaps
        HashMap<String, Integer> totalScores = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<>();
        // Compute the word total scores and counts using the appropriate method.
        computeScoreAndCounts(reviews, totalScores, wordCount);
        // Build a HashMap of average scores
        HashMap<String, Double> avgScoresMap = new HashMap<>();//I'm assuming this is empty

        for (String wordKey : reviews) {
            
            if (!avgScoresMap.containsKey(wordKey)) {
                double avgScore = (double) (totalScores.get(wordKey) / wordCount.get(wordKey)); //I think this is why it doesn't work
                avgScoresMap.put(wordKey, avgScore);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(avgScoresMap);
    }
```